# Angular HttpInterceptor to encrypt and decrypt request and response respectively

Tags: angular, async-await, angular-http-interceptors

In angular application I want to encrypt the request and send it to server, also decrypt the response when receiving.

I have created a HttpInterceptor for both this task.

I am able to encrypt the request and it is working fine, But while decrypting response I am not able to do this.

Note : Both encrypt and decrypt are async methods:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
    ) {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
return from(this.encryptRequest(req)).pipe(
        switchMap((data) => {
            return next.handle(data);
        }),
        tap(
            (event:any) => {
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    this.decryptResponse(event).then((res:any)=>{
                      return next.handle(res);
                    });

                }else{
                    return event;
                }

            },
            (error):any => {
                  //......
            },
        ),
       
    );
    }

async encryptRequest(request: HttpRequest<any>) {
//..encryption logic
}

async decryptResponse(response: HttpResponse<any>) {
//...decryption logic
 }
    }
```

But The decrypted response is not reaching to actual API call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tap` operator allows you to use the notifications emitted in the observable to perform parallel actions outside the observable pipeline(side-effects). So using tap the notifications emitted in the observable are not transform.

To transform the notifications you need to use one of the `map` operators. In this case since you also want to map the response to an async process, you can use again the `switchMap` operator.

```
return from(this.encryptRequest(req)).pipe(
  switchMap((data) => next.handle(data)),
  switchMap((event) =>
    event instanceof HttpResponse
      ? from(this.decryptResponse(event))
      : of(event)
  )
);
```

cheers

Comment: Thanks, its working, also working with mergeMap